# (Surface) using an invalid surface, identity=677 should be 683

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, monogame

I am porting my WP8 app to Android using MonoGame 3.2 and VS2012. After getting the app launching and running fine, I press the home button, then re-launch it (resume), and I get a black screen, nothing is visible. I could hear the app music going on, and when I tap at known button positions, I can hear the app respond, so it is running, but the screen is black. I opened the device log and found this line from my app:

> [Surface] using an invalid surface, identity=677 should be 683

I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

On Android this sequence of "button" taps doesn't cause the app to be relaunched (as in stopped and started from scratch). Instead, the last activity of the app is resumed (and if needed rebuild). Just guessing here, but maybe you need to look at what you are doing during onCreate, onResume and onPause...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in MonoGame which got recently fixed in their Github page.